# SOQL with Date filter in WHERE clause

Tags: apex, soql, query, datetime, date

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<StaffReport__c> getUserReports(String UserId, Date startDate, Date endDate) {

      
    return [Select Date__c from StaffReport__c where User__c =: UserId AND Date__c >=: startDate AND Date__c <=: endDate ORDER BY Date__c ]; }
```

Here i am passing **startDate** date and **endDate** in Date format,
But it is appending timestamp in Query like 2019-06-01 00:00:00

> I need to remove timestamp from Date and use it in Query

I am Using below methods to remove

> Datetime.newInstance(sd.year(), sd.month(), sd.day()).format('yyy-MM-dd')
>
> this will result 2019-06-01 but cant assign it to **Date** type

but at the End **Date__c** is Date type need to convert it from **Datetime** to **Date**,

Again appending 00:00:00

Any solution for this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. Your code is already correct. The `00:00:00` that you see in logs is an artifact of how `System.debug()` outputs date information. You can validate this by doing

```
System.debug(Date.today());
```

You'll see

> 08:52:23:002 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|2019-06-14 00:00:00

in the log. That's just how Dates are output. There is nothing wrong with your query, and you are already doing the right thing by using Apex binding to inject these values into the query.

Answer (score 0):

@Here, i solved like this:

FROM Component:

`<lightning:input  type="Date" label="Start" value="{!v.startDate}"/>`

in Controller.js:

`var startDateString = component.get("v.startDate");`

in Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<StaffReport__c> getUserReports(String UserId, String startDateString, String endDateString) {
Date startDate = Date.valueOf(startDateString);
Date endDate = Date.valueOf(endDateString);
    return [Select Date__c from StaffReport__c where User__c =: UserId AND Date__c >=: startDate AND Date__c <=: endDate ORDER BY Date__c ]; }
```